# Cannot acess image url in the New York Times API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to access results.media.media-metadata.url to dynamically put a URL src attribute and display the image of the news, but I can only access as far as results. Media, anything after that returns undefined or throws an error.

I've tried:

```
latestNews[i]['media']['media-metadata']['url']

latestNews[i][media][media-metadata][url]

latestNews[i]media.[media-metadata].url

latestNews[i]media.media-metadata.url
```

the code after de response from the API:

JSON URL: https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/shared/1/facebook.json?api-key=Dsak6ljecPclOkCgEeAdB1dmdr1bEqAC

```
let output = "";
      let latestNews = newsdata.results; //newsdata is the response

      for (var i in latestNews) {
        console.log(latestNews[i]['media']) //----> this works and outputs the object but i cant go any further.
        output += `
          <div class="col l4 m6 s12">
          <div class="card medium hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src = "#" class = "responsive-img" //--> the src is where i want to put the url
 alt = "${latestNews[i].title}" >
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title activator"><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
              <h6 class="truncate">Title: <a href="${latestNews[i].url}" title="${latestNews[i].title}">${latestNews[i].title}</a></h6>
              <p><b>Author</b>: ${latestNews[i].byline} </p>
              <p><b>News source</b>: ${latestNews[i].source} </p>
              <p><b>Published Date</b>: ${latestNews[i].published_date} </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-reveal">
              <span class="card-title"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
              < p> <b> Description </b>: ${latestNews[i].abstract}</>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action">
              <a href="${latestNews[i].url}" target="_blank" class="btn">Read More</a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        `;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `media` is array
- `media-metadata` is array too

It should be like `results[0].media[0]["media-metadata"][0].url`

Comment: Guys thank you so much i ended up getting help from my brother and we figured out together, thank you that is the solution to get the biggerr image latestNews[i].media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url

Answer (score 0):

the media object and the media-metadata objects are an array. So you need so do this instead:

```
latestNews[i]['media'][0]['media-metadata'][0].url //or which ever size image you want, so pick from the list.
```

Comment: Guys thank you so much i ended up getting help from my brother and we figured out together, thank you that is the solution to get the biggerr image latestNews[i].media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url

Comment: @JoaoPauloCCN, How did you get the URL? I cannot find the whole path.

Comment: Man, its been so long ago, but if u want u can take a look on my github https://github.com/Razikale365/News-Api-New-York-Times-Converted, so sorry for taking two years to respond i did not see the notification... Edit: Idk if the API still works today

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you so much i ended up getting help from my brother and we figured out together, thank you that is the solution to get the bigger image url :

latestNews[i].media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url
or newsdata.results[i].media[0]["media-metadata"][2].url

This community is awesome:D